# What does “papers” refer to in daily English? Does it refer to newspapers or anything else?

Tags: meaning

Yesterday on the subway train, I saw two men from The US talking, and I heard, overheard actually, one of them said "She was waving a sheaf of papers", I just want to know what "papers" means exactly in daily English. Did that man mean "newspapers" or "paper documents"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operative definition of [sheaf](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheaf) here is:

> : a group of things fastened together

This originally derived from the meaning *a bunch of stalks and ears of grain that are tied together after being cut.* A bunch of papers fastened together sort of resembled a sheaf of grain and the term was transferred.

Here is a sheaf of grain:
[image]

And here is a sheaf of papers:
[image]

In practice, an unbound stack of papers is often referred to as a sheaf as well.

Comment: Very good explanation, but, I still want to know if "papers" can refer to "newspapers"?

Comment: I realize I have only indirectly answered the meaning of *papers* here. But I think the use of the word sheaf (as well as the use of the plural *papers*) is the key to knowing that they are talking about a stack of sheet paper and not a newspaper.

Comment: Probably the only person for whom it makes sense to talk about a stack of papers and mean newspapers is the paperboy.

Comment: AND  you'd never refer to a stack of newspapers as *a sheaf*

Comment: @Jim: Lots of people have a stack of newspapers delivered to their desk every morning who are not paperboys. For instances, ministers and journalists might have a stack of newspapers delivered to them.

Comment: @Matt - Librarians, too.

Answer (score 5):

When I hear "a sheaf of papers," I immediately assume standard letter-sized papers – in other words, a stack of letters, or maybe ungraded exams (if the person was a teacher), or maybe documents from work.

On the other hand, if the person had newspapers, and I wanted to use the word "sheaf" for some reason (maybe this is recycling day), I could imagine myself saying "a sheaf of newspapers."

> I saw Larry carrying a sheaf of newspapers down to the curb.

However, I wouldn't refer to "a sheaf of newspapers" as "a sheaf of papers." In the context of "sheaf," *papers* means *paper documents*.

Here's where it gets tricky: Yes, I **can** use the word *paper* when referring to a newspaper.

> Did you see the news in today's paper?

And I can even use *the papers* when I'm referring to a bundle of newspapers:

> Did you take the papers down to the curb yet?

And I can even refer to newspapers as papers when talking about sheafing:

> Grab all of last week's papers, put them in a sheaf, and take them down to the curb.

With all that said, though, I still think I'm more likely to say *sheaf of newspapers* than *sheaf of papers*, **unless there's enough surrounding context where it would be absolutely obvious what I was talking about**:

> Every morning, Larry gets *The New York Times*, *The Wall Street Journal*, and *The Christian Science Monitor* delivered to his doorstep. At the end of every week, he brings a sheaf of papers down to the curb.